# Identifying an error of java.lang.AbstractMethodError in a java program

Tags: java, exception

When I run a Java program, I get an error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-18"
>
> Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-18".

However, it does not indicate which line makes this mistake. The program has 20000 thousands of codes, I cannot check each line.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: Have you used the debugger? If so, what kind of information is it giving you?

Answer (score 0):

This error arises when trying to call some method at runtime and when referring classes are loaded on this call ,those are not supported or compatible version with the classes already present.